# Leaflet.js - Return view to starting position if all popups are closed

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've managed to get custom icon markers on a working map and popups working etc.

There's one thing I can't work out however. I've currently got the map to zoom in and center on popups when they are opened. What I'd like is for the map to return to the starting position when all popups are closed.

I did find a snippet that returned the map to the starting position on close, but it triggered when you clicked from one popup to another. I guessed it did what I asked, but it's not great for usability.

I have a standard setup, but with the following added:

```
function markerOnClick(e) {
    var latLngs = [e.target.getLatLng()];
    var markerBounds = L.latLngBounds(latLngs);
    maphitchin.fitBounds(markerBounds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to keep a count of how many popups are open in the map with the [`popupopen` and `popupclose` events of `L.Map`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-popup-events)...

```
var openPopupsCount = 0;
map.on('popupopen',  function(){ openPopupsCount++; });
map.on('popupclose', function(){ openPopupsCount--; });
```

...and run whatever you want when that count reaches zero during such a `popupclose` event:

```
map.on('popupclose', function(){ 
    openPopupsCount--;
    if (openPopupsCount === 0) {
        map.fitBounds(initialBounds);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Would this be the best method if there is only ever one popup open at a time?

Comment: Define "best" .

Comment: Regretfully, this doesn't seem to want to work for me.I have a fiddle set up at https://jsfiddle.net/heretotravel/xped71gL/44/

Comment: Pal, you're attaching the `popupclose` event handler twice, decrementing the counter twice per `popupclose` event.

Comment: Ahh, yes! Of course. Okay, so the script works (except fitbounds(initialBounds) which I changed to SetView()). The script though doesn't like it when the user clicks from one popup to another. It goes back to centre instead of centering the popup, like it's not counting the new popup. (Now on version 50). Thanks for perservering with me, only started with js yesterday.

Comment: Well, when "the user clicks from one popup to another", the current popup closes *then* the next one opens, so there is a moment in time when there are zero popups in the map, right? You got what you wished for ;-)